# Erro com caractéres acentuados

Tags: php, html, codificação-de-caracteres

Boa tarde,

Os caracteres acentuados no meu sistema não estão funcionando quando trago do banco de dados, ficam assim �, eu já tentei colocar o meta tag, já tentei salvar o arquivo com uma codificação diferente, mas não funciona..

OBS: os texto escritos por mim no código carregam certinho, são apenas as informações que vem do banco que não carregam

OBS²: Quando rodo a consulta no SQLYog todos os acentos estão lá corretamente

Comment: experimente aplicar utf8_encode($variavel) na variável que é printada do banco

Comment: Tudo depende de qual o `encoding` usada no banco, esse caractere  � aparece quando você tenta imprimir  um texto que tem algum `encoding ` diferente de `utf8` em `utf-8`. A solução do @AnthraxisBR deve funcionar... Mas talvez seja mais interessante mudar o `encoding` do banco ou do seu arquivo `php`

Comment: @AnthraxisBR essa função funciona, porém ainda gostária de uma solução mais "global"
Obrigado

Comment: @edsonalves infelizmente não tenho como fazer isso, a base de dados da empresa foi estruturada a um tempo já e tem varios sistemas que a utilizam.

Obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use o seu metodo de query para executar a query

```
SET NAMES (sua codificação de caracteres EX: utf8); <- isto diz para a conecxão com o banco que os caracteres estão em tal codificação
```

E no php

```
mb_http_input("mesma codificação de caracteres do banco");
mb_http_output("mesma codificação de caracteres do banco");
mb_regex_encoding("mesma codificação de caracteres do banco");
mb_internal_encoding("mesma codificação de caracteres do banco");
```

Lembrando que estas configurações podem ser feitas no seu php.ini , mas se a hospedagem for compartilhada provavelmente não vai conseguir edita-lo

Comment: Lembrando que estas configurações devem estar no inicio da execução do codifo e logo apos a abertura da conecxao com o banco